# Extracting id number from a varchar in PostgreSQL

Tags: regex, postgresql, numeric

I have a field that contains mixed data with an id number that I want extract to another column.  The column I wish to extract from has some records that match the format 'lastname, firstname-ID'.  I only want to strip the 'ID' part, and from those columns who have a '-' and numbers following it.

So what I was trying to do was...

```
update data.xml_customerqueryrs
set new_id = regexp_replace(name, '[a-z]A-Z]', '')
where name like '%-%';
```

I know there is something minor that I need to fix, but I am not sure as the postgresql documentation for pattern matching  doesn't really do a good job covering searching for only numerics.

Comment: Duh...


    update data.xml_customerqueryrs
    set new_id = substring(name, strpos(name, '-'), length(name))
    where name like '%-%';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you can also do:

```
new_id = substr(name, strpos(name, '-'), length(name))
```

Ref: [Strings](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html)

Comment: Includes the '-' in the result. Also, please don't link to ancient version 8.0 of the manual, just because Google can't get their results straight. I fixed it. Consider [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108714/best-way-to-reference-the-postgresql-manual).

Answer (score 3):

If you actually `only want to strip the 'ID' part`:

```
new_id = regexp_replace(name, '-.*?$', '')
```

Or, if you, in fact, want to *extract* the ID part:

```
new_id = substring(name, '-(.*?)$')
```

I use the [`*?` quantifier](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-matching.html#POSIX-QUANTIFIERS-TABLE), so that only the last part is extracted, where a name has a `-` in it. Like:

```
Skeet-Gravell,John-1234
```

[String functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html) in *current* manual